# Shopware 6 - Set manufacturer logo fixed position

Tags: css, shopware, shopware6

the manufacturer logo on the product details page of Shopware6 constantly changes its position depending on how big the logo of the manufacturer is. We have now trimmed the logos so that they no longer have a white border. The logos of the manufacturers are of course always different sizes so that they are never flush with the product title.

We want the logo to be flush with the product title, no matter how big the logo is. How can we force Shopware6 to do this?

EDIT:
I´m using this but the top seems changing depending on the size of the manufacturer-logo:

```
.product-detail-manufacturer {
margin-top: -125px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For a pure CSS solution you could [add custom styling](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-styling) or [use a plugin](https://store.shopware.com/en/dne5719820551438f/custom-javascript/css-manager-for-shopware-6.html) and set the items of the detail headline to be aligned at the top:

```css
.product-detail-headline {
    align-items: start !important;
}
```

Comment: This CSS-Class is not existent in Shopware6. Allthough I don´t want to change the position of the "headline" I want to change the position of the manufacturer-logo. The CSS-Class of the logo is .product-detail-manufacturer-logo - At the moment I´m using this: .product-detail-manufacturer {
    margin-top: -125px;
} but it dont work.

Comment: [It does exist](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/5d3efa8b3e8d09105c34e6de4de2ef4efaff50dd/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/page/product-detail/index.html.twig#L17) and has so since the earliest versions.  That is unless you're using a theme that changes the markup complete and then you probably can't expect much help here. Also the element which is `.product-detail-headline` uses a flex layout, hence the `align-items` property regards its children, which are both the actual headline and the manufacturer logo. This will make both child elements aligned at the top.